# Writing class libraries on Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I'm new to Xamarin , and I need a clarification on using Xamarin in the following case :
1. I need to write code not related to UI (I mean not only developing screens).
2. I need to develope code related to advanced .net libraries (Networking, Threading , ...)

Is Xamarin relevant in my case ?

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: I wrote an answer and then became unsure I'd understood you correctly. Do you mean using Xamarin Studio for a non-Xamarin specific library, of using Xamarin (whether through Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio) for a mobile-specific library that would be used in another Xamarin-based project, or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Code related to UI:**

Till date xamarin studio provided direct support for creating android UI. But for IOS, one had to use XCODE for UI.

But, the recent release of xamarin is said to support UI for IOS as well. see here : http://xamarin.com/studio
 But for running the simulator, you anyways need to peer your PC with a mac.

**Code related to libraries:**

Any back end code that you wish to share across platforms including Database, threading, Networking etc can be written very well using xamarin. Even existing dlls and jars can be added efficiently.
This blog will help you : http://www.codemag.com/Article/1401051

Hope it helps.
Thanks and cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Xamarin is relevant in your case. You can create C# Classes, functions, models etc and share them across multiple platforms.  This is achieved by making the shared portions a Portable Class library and referencing the PCL in your platform specific projects. You can also use Xamarin.Forms to even share UI design.